# Add column name to first column

Tags: python, pandas

How do I add column name to the first column for the Sales Rep

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1], ['John Collier', 'Mike Rogers']
       codes=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])

               Jan   Feb   Mar 
 John Collier  $200  $140 $210   
 Mike Rogers   $180  $160 $205
```

Look Like this

```
  Sales Rep    Jan   Feb   Mar 
 John Collier  $200  $140 $210   
 Mike Rogers   $180  $160 $205
```

I had to stack the information around so I am unsure if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: Please show your df.to_dict() to us

Comment: Also that is index not columns

Comment: I read an excel file for the data and had to rearrange it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I reset the index and renamed the column then dropped a column.

```
df = df.reset_index()

level_0    level_1
 0       John Collier
 0       Mike Richards

df = df.rename(columns={"level_1": "Sales Rep"})
df = df.drop(columns=["level_0"])
df
```

To make it look like this

```
 Sales Rep    Jan   Feb   Mar 
 John Collier  $200  $140 $210   
 Mike Rogers   $180  $160 $205
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `df.index.name = 'Sales Rep'`

Comment: what is the output ?

Comment: you have to print df again to get the output

Comment: I get Sales Rep to print out but I need to reference the index heading to group and it doesn't appear when I print the dataframe.